# Moving Magento "Add to Cart" button to new file not working

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7, php

I want to move Add to cart button from `view.phtml` file to `2columns-right.phtml` file and I am cant make it work. What I did is that I copied `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>` from `view.phtml` file to `2columns-right.phtml` and it does not appear at all. I did Flush Magento cache too but nothing again.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Take a look @ /layout/catalog.xml you will notice that in `<catalog_product_view>` ... you declare $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') in your xml with `<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You should get familiar with magento layout system. To make possible `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>` work in `2columns-right.phtml` this block should be declared as child block of root block (the root is the block that is rendered with `2columns-right.phtml`). Actually, I don't see much sense in moving add to cart to other template, because `addtocart.phtml` itself is just a button that submits whole form that is located at `catalog/product/view.phtml`. If you take it out of there it won't work.

Comment: yes I know it wont work without the form, I will move the form too, just dont know why the buttons is not appearing inside previously mentioned file.

Comment: Hi this answer is actually making sense but I was a newbie in magento so I'm getting to know the scheme of this framework, for me I need to display this on a specific page using the declaration of {{block type="catalog/product_view" product_id="3" template="catalog/product/view.phtml"}} over the content somehow make it appear on the cms page because we are using a component in joomla to have it display the magento product pages over the site and all that we need is the add to cart form together with it's configurable attributes to add the product on the cart.

Answer (score 1):

First of all i agree with nevermourn you can not get childhtml if you havn't declared it. But you can use

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

By using this in `2columns-right.phtml` you will get `addtocart.phtml` for sure.

Comment: Hi Kashif, welcome to SO and contributing! Would you please test your answer on a dev server to make sure? I would, but at the moment only have live server configured. It looks correct to me, but I recall a time when something like this didn't work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, i have tested it on magento 1.7x and it works fine but if you have home page with `2columns-right.phtml` than it will throw an error because product data doesnt exist. But you can prevent that by adding condition like 'if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName()=='catalog')'

Answer (score 0):

in order to call add to cart button by using

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
```

on the page you desire in layout/local.xml

```
<yourModule_YourController_yourAction>
   <reference name="content">
      <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</yourModule_YourController_yourAction>
```